# Move data from qcow2 image to another guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager, qcow2

I have a corrupted guest and I cannot reboot the guest. So I have mounted my guest to my host and this is what I have in `/mnt`

```
$ sudo ls /mnt
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib64  lost+found 
media   mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz 
vmlinuz.old
```

I have started a new guest and I want to move the data to that working guest so that all my data is saved etc. Kinda like what you do in aws. But I am at lost as to where to go from here.

```
Data: it is webserver with Postgres database

HOST OS (Desktop)
Package: qemu-system-x86
Version: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Source: qemu
Origin: Ubuntu
```

I cannot log into guest so cannot tell the version
It puts me to login loop. Guest is not desktop, it is ONLY terminal

Comment: added more information

Comment: that kills the whole purpose of what I am trying to fo. I need to bring the server back up as it is